# SQL Return datas from the second table based on the data of the first table

Tags: sql-server

I have two SQL Server tables that are not linked together (No join) and I want to get the data from the second table based on the data of the first table. In the first table I have this:

Table 1

```
id  name
----------
4   BOX-A 
8   PART-D
```

Table 2

```
id  name
------------
14  BOX-A1
25  BOX-A2
38  TOOL-A1
39  TOOL-A2
40  PART-D1
41  PART-D2
```

What I want to do is that for each name found in table 1, I want to return all the matches in the table 2, so at the end I will have something like this:

```
id  name
-----------
14  BOX-A1
25  BOX-A2
40  PART-D1
41  PART-D2
```

Comment: If you are dealing with non-linked DBs, please look into using [OPENDATASOURCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx) to connect to non-linked databases. This will allow you to pass in connection string information to access the second database/table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` or `exists`:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t2.name like concat(t1.name, '%'));
```

Comment: Excellent ! I just want to add a fix : it's concat(t1.name, '%') and not  concat(t2.name, '%') :)